# Why can't change ip ubuntu server 20

Tags: server, 20.04, dns, dhcp, bind

In host main, has service dhcp with bind9

And configure for distribute ip static for one new mac 11:27:00:6a:5b => 192.16.2.23.

But when installed the system operation Ubuntu 20, services dhpc distribute 192.168.2.115, It's was in other range ip.

Version System

> Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-70-generic x86_64)

I’m try changes but can't receive the correct ip, where configure file for receive new ip

I'm have others ip's for mac It's Work, for server debian and windows servers

[image]

Comment: Please show us your dhcpd configuration files. If your general dynamic IP address pool is declared before your MAC based reserved list, then yes you will never get the mac based address (well, not never, but it is difficult). The trick is to put the MAC based stuff first. How do I know this? Because I had this problem for years.

Comment: Yes my dhcp has a range of ips reserved for the servers, but when installed and configured the system on another machine it was still on the network, and took an ip out of that range, when put the machine together with the other servers, and configured my dhcp to distribuite a new ip, it doesn’t change anymore, I think there’s a file or cache that isn’t letting it change

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  There is no such release. Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format (year.month of release) for all server & desktop releases, the *yy* being used only for IoT and specialist appliance/device releases (also suitable for cloud use) that can use *snap* packages only.  By Ubuntu 20 do you mean Ubuntu Core 20?  as it's a different product to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (desktop or server).

Comment: The MAC of your text and your picture are not the same.

Comment: Yes same, that first example, second real configuration,